# Como llamar a un servicio dentro de un controlador en laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8, laravel-6, laravel-7

tengo un consulta si tengo un controlador, como puedo llamar a un servicio dentro de este, por ejemplo en este controlador quisiera llamar a otro microservicio y enviar un objeto en ese servicio:

```
public function verDatosCiteUsuario(Request $request,$id)
    {

        //Verificando si el usuario creo el cite, si creo puede ver todo el arbol, caso contrario solo el padre
        $VerificarCreacion = AtSecuenciaCartaInternaUsuario::whereNull('d_fecha_eliminacion')
                                                           ->select('n_id_usuario')
                                                           ->where('n_id',$id)
                                                           ->firstOrFail();

        if($VerificarCreacion->n_id_usuario ==  $request->user()->n_id)
        {
            $SecuenciaUsuario = AtSecuenciaCartaInternaUsuario::with('carta_interna','usuario','children','padre')
                                                               ->whereNull('d_fecha_eliminacion')
                                                               ->where('n_id',$id)
                                                               ->firstOrFail();
        } else {

            $SecuenciaUsuario = AtSecuenciaCartaInternaUsuario::with('carta_interna','usuario','padre')
                ->whereNull('d_fecha_eliminacion')
                ->where('n_id',$id)
                ->firstOrFail();
        }

//        $datos_otro_servicio = ?
        return response()->json([
            'codigo' => 200,           
            'data'=> $SecuenciaUsuario,
            'data_otro_servicio'=>$datos_otro_servicio 
            'mensaje' => 'Datos de secuencia',
        ], 200);
    }
```

Gracias anticipadas.

Comment: A qué te refieres con "llamar a otro microservicio"? Es un servicio dentro de laravel o es algo externo?

Comment: porloscerros, es decir llamar a un microservicio o servicio dentro de un controlador, en el ejemplo como llamaria aqui: "//        $datos_otro_servicio = ?"

Comment: Por eso te preguntaba que es ese servicio. Es una clase de php de laravel? En ese caso podrías inyectarla como dependencia. Si es un servicio externo, por ejemplo una API que consumes, podrías usar el HTTP Client de laravel

Comment: Gracias por la aclaracion estimado porloscerros, saludos.